# How to use regex for generic number?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex rules for the `replace` method:

```
svg = svg.replace(/NS1:data:longestSeries=\"(.*?)\"/g, '');
svg = svg.replace(/NS2:data:longestSeries=\"(.*?)\"/g, '');
svg = svg.replace(/NS3:data:longestSeries=\"(.*?)\"/g, '');
svg = svg.replace(/NS4:data:longestSeries=\"(.*?)\"/g, '');
svg = svg.replace(/NS5:data:longestSeries=\"(.*?)\"/g, '');
```

How can I create a single rule which implies all of the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a character set for all the digits that are allowed:

```
/NS[1-5]:data:longestSeries=".*?"/g
```

or if this is for every digit, simply use the `\d` specifier:

```
/NS\d:data:longestSeries=".*?"/g
```

Also as @Utkanos mentioned, you don't need to escape the double quotes since they don't carry any special meaning in a regex pattern.

Lastly, you don't need parentheses around `.*?` since you are not using the captured group for anything.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that there's no need to escape quotes.

Comment: If it weren't consecutive numbers, (?:1|2|3|4|5), but for the given problem, the [1-5] solution is beautiful.